# How to create multiple BuildContext inside widget

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

This is my code

```dart
Widget homeDashBoardCards(title, image, BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DashBoardScreen(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

and I need to just be able to change this **context** to chose the page, instead of creating a lot of **Widgets**.

```dart
homeDashBoardCards('Categories', 'chii-icon.png', context),
```

like creating 2 cases or more in this one...

```dart
builder: (context) => DashBoardScreen
```

Just as an example:

```dart
builder: (context) => case "1" = DashBoardScreen
                      case "2" = FavoriteScreen
```

Thank you guys...

Comment: Take a look at my answer and tell me if that's what you wanted, because your question is not very clear. If it isn't what you want, I can edit the answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. What I think the Problem Is

What you want is not 100% clear from the question, but I think you simply want a function that would have a `switch` inside returning which page the user should go to?

In that case, you might want to check out:

- [Flutter's tutorials on routing](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)
- [`switch` statement in Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#switch-and-case)

## 2. One Possible Solution

1. Create a `switch` function for deciding which page to switch to. Instead of using `String`s, I highly suggest using `enum`s. But both are possible.

   ```dart
   enum Screens {dashboard, favorite}

   Widget screenSwitcher(Screens screenEnum) {
     switch (screenEnum) {
       case Screens.dashboard:
         return DashBoardScreen();
       case Screens.favorite:
         return FavoriteScreen();
       default:
         throw Exception;
     }
   }
   ```

   Note that, if you have a non-empty `case` clause ending with a `return`, `throw` or `continue`, you don't need a `break`. The `default` clause doesn't need a `break`.
2. Return the screen when routing by calling the switcher function — you can obviously create more parameters for the functions, if necessary —:

   ```dart
   Widget homeDashBoardCards(title, image, Screens screenEnum, BuildContext context) {
     return GestureDetector(
       onTap: () => Navigator.push(
         context,
         MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => screenSwitcher(screenEnum),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
   ```

## 3. Further Reading

Your code will be much simpler and easier to read if you use *Named Routing*, as mentioned in the first section of this answer. Additionally, if routing is very important to your app and complicated, you might want to consider looking for or creating a package in the [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=routing) package host.

If you accept the solution code I shared above, you're passing variables through different widgets, which is not very object-oriented and also not the Flutter way. You should then consider state sharing packages to work around that. Two of the most notable ones are the [BLoC](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) and the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) packages, but you can also do it with `rxdart` and the `get_it` package, check [this video](https://youtu.be/3tm-R7ymwhc) by Fireship for a great summary.

Comment: thank you so much, that worked for me... just why when i go to the Dashboard screen i lose the bottom bar? thank you so much for your help

Comment: Did you create the bottom bar inside the scaffold of the previous one? In that case, it will be attached to the previous screen then. You will then either have to recreate the widget in every screen or find a way to share it. But I think this is a topic for another question, unfortunately.

Comment: If you want more content on state management, though, I've found [this video](https://youtu.be/3tm-R7ymwhc) by Fireship, which is very illuminating, specially the part about `rxdart`.